# Create a function to recode all character variables in one go

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I want to recode multiple fields for e.g. gender, marital status, education to numeric for eg. `male=1`, `female=2` & so on

```
convert <- function(x,y,z)
{
  if(x[[y]]==z) { 
    x$y=as.factor(1)
  } else {
    x$y=as.factor(2)
  }
}
train$Gender <- convert(train,Gender,“Male”)
```

But this throws an Error

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level.

Can some one help out?

Comment: Please provide an example for `x, y, z`

Comment: You can't use `$y` if `y` is computed and you want to use its value rather than the literal name "y". Use `x[[y]] <- ...` instead (just like you did in the `if` statement).

Comment: @JDL it still throws the same error

Comment: Another comment: beware of `as.factor(1)` and `as.factor(2)` — they will not have the other level by default (e.g. `as.factor(2)` will not have levels `1` and `2`, just a single level `2`). You may find very confusing things happen if you try and select or merge them later...

Comment: @New2015, please post exactly what you tried. I spotted yet another bug: your code is not vectorised, and will not work if `x[[y]]` has length more than one. I suspect what you wanted to do was create a factor of the same length of `x[[y]]`, where each element is 1 if the corresponding element of `x[[y]]` was equal to `z`, else 2. Your code does not do that (you might use `ifelse`)

Comment: @JDL but nothing seems to work. I do not want to do it the tidyverse way. Instead I want to create a function which can do it for multiple columns.

Comment: @JDL I want to recode 1 where gender is male & 2 where gender is female

Comment: It is often easier to loop over column names, for example `for (n in colnames(train)) train[[n]] <- ...`. I'd also strongly recommend using TRUE and FALSE instead of as.factor(1) and as.factor(2)..

Comment: @New2015 The variables should still be factors, but have numeric levels, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution for the conversion you've tried would be:

```
df <- data.frame(Gender = c("male", "male", "female", "male"))

convert <- function(data, var, label){
  data[,var] <- ifelse(is.na(data[,var]), NA, 
                            ifelse(data[,var] == label, 1, 2))
  return(as.factor(data[,var]))
}

df$Gender <- convert(df, "Gender", "male")

> df
  Gender
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      1
```

If you just want to convert your factors with string levels into numeric levels, you can use this simple command to do it for as many variables as you want in one go:

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = factor(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE), 1:5, labels = LETTERS[1:5]),
                 var2 = factor(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE), 1:5, labels = LETTERS[6:10]),
                 var3 = factor(sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE), 1:5, labels = LETTERS[11:15]))

> df
   var1 var2 var3
1     B    F    O
2     A    F    M
3     D    F    N
4     E    F    O
5     B    H    N
6     B    F    M
7     A    F    O
8     E    I    O
9     C    J    N
10    E    J    O
```

Now use `lapply` to loop over the columns you want to change, and use `as.factor(as.numeric())` to first convert to numeric, then back to factor with numeric levels:

```
df[, c("var1", "var2")] <- lapply(df[, c("var1", "var2")], function(x) as.factor(as.numeric(x)))

> df
   var1 var2 var3
1     2    1    O
2     1    1    M
3     4    1    N
4     5    1    O
5     2    3    N
6     2    1    M
7     1    1    O
8     5    4    O
9     3    5    N
10    5    5    O

> class(df$var1)
[1] "factor"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution so the variable to be converted has to be vectorized first & then apply "ifelse"

Comment: I've reduced the function, the temporary vector was unnecessary. Won't make much of a difference, but it may be faster on huge data. This will only work on factors with two levels, though.

Comment: yes I was wondering the same & that's the reason I was keen on using if & else instead of "ifelse".What is the best way to handle variables with multiple levels?

Comment: That depends. Do you just want numeric levels, or do you need to assign specific numbers to specific levels?

Comment: I just want numeric levels

Comment: That is very simple, I will include a solution in the answer.

Comment: thanks for this. I tried doing the same but I had missed on (as.numeric(x)) & was simply trying to apply an as.factor. Thanks again.